# ClassCastException when using clojure.string/split

Tags: clojure, classcastexception, hiccup

I'm writing a website using clojure hiccup for html and clojure garden for css. Now I'm having trouble using clojure.string/split to split a path for the filename. So for `some/path/file.md` I want `file`.

For context here's the code snippet, where the problem is

```clj
(defn blog-card [post]
  [:a.blog-post-card-link {:href (->> (:location post)
                                      (string/split #"/")
                                      last
                                      (string/replace ".md" ""))}
    [:div.blog-post-card
      -- rest of content -- ]])
```

now this function gets called here

```clj
(defn blog-content []
  [:div.blog-content
    [:div.blog-post-cards-list
      (let [json-str (slurp "resources/public/markdown/posts/all-posts.json")
            posts (json/parse-string json-str true)]
        (map blog-card (reverse posts)))]])
```

where `json` is `[cheshire.core :as json]` and `string` is `[clojure.string :as string]`. The `all-posts.json` looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "title": "Test article #1",
    "description": "This article is just a place-filler for development.",
    "image": "images/mountain.jpg",
    "date": "10 Oct 2023",
    "author": "Elías Hauksson",
    "location": "markdown/posts/test-post01.md"
  },
  -- more test entries --
]
```

So with this example, what I'd like to achieve is, that when the card is pressed, one gets redirected to `/test-post01`

Now when I try to run this code I get the following error message

```
HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.regex.Pattern (java.lang.String and java.util.regex.Pattern are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
URI:    /blog
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.regex.Pattern (java.lang.String and java.util.regex.Pattern are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
SERVLET:    -
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.regex.Pattern (java.lang.String and java.util.regex.Pattern are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
Caused by:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.regex.Pattern (java.lang.String and java.util.regex.Pattern are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at clojure.string$split.invokeStatic(string.clj:219)
    at clojure.string$split.invoke(string.clj:219)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.blog$blog_card.invokeStatic(blog.clj:10)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.blog$blog_card.invoke(blog.clj:8)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__5935.invoke(core.clj:2772)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:51)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:535)
    at clojure.core$seq__5467.invokeStatic(core.clj:139)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__5935.invoke(core.clj:2763)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:51)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:535)
    at clojure.core$seq__5467.invokeStatic(core.clj:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:662)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:139)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invoke(compiler.clj:133)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3063$G__3058__3068.invoke(compiler.clj:119)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__5935.invoke(core.clj:2770)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:51)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:535)
    at clojure.core$seq__5467.invokeStatic(core.clj:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:662)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:139)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invoke(compiler.clj:133)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3063$G__3058__3068.invoke(compiler.clj:119)
    at hiccup.compiler$render_element.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:129)
    at hiccup.compiler$render_element.invoke(compiler.clj:123)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3078.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:136)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3078.invoke(compiler.clj:133)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3063$G__3058__3068.invoke(compiler.clj:119)
    at clojure.core$map$fn__5935.invoke(core.clj:2770)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:51)
    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:535)
    at clojure.core$seq__5467.invokeStatic(core.clj:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:662)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:139)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3080.invoke(compiler.clj:133)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3063$G__3058__3068.invoke(compiler.clj:119)
    at hiccup.compiler$render_element.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:129)
    at hiccup.compiler$render_element.invoke(compiler.clj:123)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3078.invokeStatic(compiler.clj:136)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3078.invoke(compiler.clj:133)
    at hiccup.compiler$fn__3063$G__3058__3068.invoke(compiler.clj:119)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.base$base$fn__1001.invoke(base.clj:26)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.base$base.invokeStatic(base.clj:26)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.base$base.invoke(base.clj:25)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.blog$blog_page.invokeStatic(blog.clj:35)
    at eliashaukssoncom.views.blog$blog_page.invoke(blog.clj:34)
    at eliashaukssoncom.handler$fn__1026.invokeStatic(handler.clj:13)
    at eliashaukssoncom.handler$fn__1026.invoke(handler.clj:13)
    at compojure.core$wrap_response$fn__2214.invoke(core.clj:158)
    at compojure.core$wrap_route_middleware$fn__2198.invoke(core.clj:128)
    at compojure.core$wrap_route_info$fn__2203.invoke(core.clj:137)
    at compojure.core$wrap_route_matches$fn__2207.invoke(core.clj:146)
    at compojure.core$routing$fn__2222.invoke(core.clj:185)
    at clojure.core$some.invokeStatic(core.clj:2718)
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2709)
    at compojure.core$routing.invokeStatic(core.clj:185)
    at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:182)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
    at compojure.core$routes$fn__2226.invoke(core.clj:192)
    at ring.middleware.resource$wrap_resource_prefer_resources$fn__596.invoke(resource.clj:25)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:384)
    at ring.adapter.jetty$proxy_handler$fn__420.invoke(jetty.clj:27)
    at ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

### What I've tried

1. replace `(:location post)` with `"some/test/path/file.md"`
2. write the function without the `->>` operator. Like this

```clj
{:href (string/replace (last (string/split (:location post) #"/")) #".md" "")}
```

**Edit: Point 2 turns out to be the correct solution (as mentioned by @Eugene_Pakhomov), it was a typo in my code that didn't make it work the first time.**

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clojure.string/split` accepts a string as the first argument and a regular expression as the second. The code in the "What I've tried" section should work. The code in the main section doesn't work because `(->> (:location post) (string/split #"/"))` is expanded into `(string/split #"/" (:location post))`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!! I had a typo in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could also do this directly with regex and for example `re-find`:

```clj
(let [post {:location "/some/path/here/foobar.md"}]
  (re-find #"([^/.]+).md" (:location post)))

=> ["foobar.md" "foobar"]
```

Where the regex says:

- `(` - open paren, start a capturing group in regex
- `[^/.]+` - match any character except (slash `/` or period `.`) one or more times (`+`).
- `)` - close capturing group
- `.md` - expect the captured group to be followed by `.md`

the returned vector contains the full match `"foobar.md"` followed by the captured group `"foobar"` which is what you are after.

If you want to use the threading macros (`->>`) this could look as follows:

```clj
(let [post {:location "/asd/adsf/asdf/foobar.md"}]
  (->> (:location post)
       (re-find #"([^/.]+).md" )
       second))

=> "foobar"
```

Or if you want to go even more concise, you can use regex [lookaround assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```clj
(re-find #"[^/.]+(?=\.md)" "/asd/adsf/asdf/foobar.md")

=> "foobar"
```

where the `(?=...)` part is a "zero-width positive lookahead". This essentially means "match a string consisting of anything except / or . followed by the string ".md" but do not make ".md" part of the match". Documentation on the regex implementation in clojure can be found on the java [pattern class javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) as clojure uses the JVM pattern implementation.

Should be noted that as for your initial example, if the path does not end with `.md`, the match will just return `nil` and not match the "file name" part. If you need arbitrary file extensions, you can do something like:

```clj
(re-find #"[^/.]+(?=\..+)" "/asd/adsf/asdf/foobar.orange")

=> "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

For work with filesystem names & paths, it is always best to use the built-in functionality of the `java.io` package.  In this case, the `File` class can safely & easily parse out pathname segments regardless of operating system.

I would solve it like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str])
  (:import
    [java.io File]))

(verify
  (let [file-obj  (File. "some/path/file.md")
        name-str  (.getName file-obj)
        name-root (first (str/split name-str #"\."))]
    (is= "file.md" name-str)
    (is= "file" name-root)))
```

Note that `(first (str/split ...))` assumes there is only a single `.` ("dot") character in the file name!  For robust code, please add error checking!